# Debugging in Visual Studio 2008/2010 - toggle off highlighting of rows

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In Debug-mode, the row currently executed is highlighted yellow and a yellow arrow is shown. Is it possible to turn the highlighting of the row off/on?

Answer (score 3):

In VS2010: Menu Debug -> Options and Settings / General - Checkbox "Highlight entire source line for breakpoints and current statement.

Comment: Actually, I work with VS2008, and the option you mean (Tools->Options->Debugging->General was not checked, but yet the lines are highlighted yellow. ??

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors.

Find "Current statement" in the list and change the background to whatever your text editor background is. You might also want to change the other "Current ..." settings.